# Module.exports with es6 import for webpack.config.ts in typescript

Tags: typescript, webpack, import

I'm using webpack with typescript with the config its self in typescript. Instructions [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-languages/#typescript)

In my root I have `webpack.config.base.ts`

```js
import webpack from "webpack";

const getConfig = ( appDir: string, distDir: string, env: any, args: any ): webpack.Configuration => {
    const config: webpack.Configuration = {
        entry: {

        },
        output: {

        },
        resolve: {
            plugins: [

            ],
            extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
        },
        devtool: "source-map",
        module: {
            rules: [
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
        ]
    };

    return config;
};

module.exports = getConfig;
```

I then have two projects each with their own `webpack.config.ts`

```js
import webpack from "webpack";
import * as path from 'path';

const getConfig = require("../../webpack.config.base");

const appDir = __dirname;
const distDir  = path.resolve(__dirname, "../AppOne.Web/wwwroot");

const getConfigFactory = (env: any, args: any): webpack.Configuration => getConfig(appDir, distDir, env, args);

module.exports = getConfigFactory;
```

This all works absolutely fine. [Here's](https://github.com/michaelbull/aurelia-split-pane/blob/master/webpack.config.ts) a full example of this factory `getConfig = () => {}` style.

My problem is when I try to change to change

```js
const getConfig = require("../../webpack.config.base");
```

To an es6 import. This is even provided as a suggestion by VS code.

[image]

When I apply this change I get

[image]

Here's my `tsconfig.json` I already have `[allowSyntheticDefaultImports][5]` enabled. Suggested [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2242#issuecomment-223384524).

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "react",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "dom"
    ],
    "target": "es5",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types/",
      "./types/"
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": { }
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./src/**/*.tsx"
  ]
}
```

But I added `export default getConfig;` anyway... and `npm run build` again. It still fails.

```
const getConfigFactory = (env: any, args: any): webpack.Configuration => getConfig(appDir, distDir, env, args);
                                                                                  ^
TypeError: webpack_config_base_1.default is not a function
```

My final attempt before smashing my head into the table was to change

```js
import getConfig from "../../webpack.config.base";
```

```js
import * as base from "../../webpack.config.base";
```

Delete the `export default getConfig;` in the `webpack.config.base.ts` and export the `const getConfig` directly as `export const getConfig`. But at that point what's the point of `module.exports = getConfig`. Not to mention it also doesn't bloody work (same issue as before)

```
const getConfigFactory = (env: any, args: any): webpack.Configuration => base.getConfig(appDir, distDir, env, args);
                                                                              ^
TypeError: base.getConfig is not a function
```

What am I missing here? Why can't I simply replace `const getConfig = require("../../webpack.config.base");` with `import getConfig from "../../webpack.config.base"`

PS.

Here's my `"scripts"` for running this

```
    "build:appone": "webpack --mode=development --config ./src/AppOne.App/webpack.config.ts",
    "build:apptwo": "webpack --mode=development --config ./src/AppTwo.App/webpack.config.ts",
```

Answer (score 7):

## What does work?

I configured *webpack* with *TypeScript* for multiple environments (e.g. `development` and `production`) with a common base configuration. To do so, I utilize:

- *Node.js* (version `11.12.0`)
- *TypeScript* (version `3.5.3`)
- *webpack* (version `4.39.1`)

### Directory Structure

Suppose the following directory structure :

```
project/
├── ...
├── webpack.common.ts
├── webpack.development.ts
└── webpack.production.ts
```

Other directory structures (such as two nested projects as in your example) will work as well. Although, you may have to adapt the paths used in the examples below.

### TypeScript Configuration

The base configuration of webpack, `webpack.common.ts`, looks as follows:

```ts
import webpack from 'webpack';

const configuration: webpack.Configuration = {
  // Your common webpack configuration...
};

export default configuration;
```

The two webpack configurations for different environments extend this base configuration using the [npm package `webpack-merge`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-merge). You can find its typings for TypeScript in the [npm package `@types/webpack-merge`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/webpack-merge). To stick with the initial example, the webpack configuration for the `development` environment looks as follows:

```ts
import webpack from 'webpack';
import merge from 'webpack-merge';
import commonWebpackConfiguration from './webpack.common';

const configuration: webpack.Configuration = merge(commonWebpackConfiguration, {
  mode: 'development'
  // Your `development`-specific configuration...
});

export default configuration;
```

Meanwhile, the webpack configuration for the `production` environment is no different to the one used for the `development` environment in terms of `import`/`export` syntax.

### Imports and Exports

As you may have noticed, I use the *ES6* `import`/`export` syntax:

```ts
export default configuration;
```

and

```ts
import commonWebpackConfiguration from './webpack.common';
```

Consequently, there is no *CommonJS* syntax for imports and exports (e.g. `module.exports` or `require`) involved which keeps the webpack configuration files clean and allows for a seamless workflow. This is actually the recommended way to work with webpack and TypeScript as per [webpack's documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-languages/#typescript).

---

## Why does your configuration *not* work?

### First Attempt

> My problem is when I try to change
>
> ```
> const getConfig = require("../../webpack.config.base");
> ```
>
> to an es6 import. This is even provided as a suggestion by VS code.

`module.exports` does indeed not have a default export (i.e. the object `module.exports` does not have any property named `default`) as the error you observed stated.
Using *ES6* default export (i.e. `export default`) actually creates an export *named* `default` just like for other named exports (e.g. `bar` in the following). This can be illustrated compiling the following TypeScript snippet:

```ts
const helloWorld = () => {
  console.log('Hello, world!');
};
const bar = 'foo';

export default helloWorld;
export { bar };
```

to JavaScript using `tsc`:

```js
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var helloWorld = function () {
    console.log('Hello, world!');
};
var bar = 'foo';
exports.bar = bar;
exports["default"] = helloWorld;
```

### Second Attempt

> But I added `export default getConfig;` anyway... and `npm run build` again. It still fails.

In this case, adding `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` (which you already have) and `esModuleInterop` (which you miss) to your TypeScript configuration `tsconfig.json` both set to `true` would remedy that issue <sup>[1](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-languages/#typescript)</sup>.

### Third Attempt

> My final attempt before smashing my head into the table was to change
>
> ```
> import getConfig from "../../webpack.config.base";
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> import * as base from "../../webpack.config.base";
> ```
>
> Delete the `export default getConfig;` in the `webpack.config.base.ts` and export the `const getConfig` directly as `export const getConfig`. But at that point what's the point of `module.exports = getConfig`.

Having

```ts
export const getConfig = () => {...};
```

and

```ts
module.exports = getConfig;
```

at the same time, will give you `base === getConfig` (as only `module.exports = getConfig;` takes effect). Consequently, calling `base.getConfig` gives `undefined` since your defined function `getConfig` does not have a property `getConfig`. Hence, "`base.getConfig` is not a function".

### Import Syntax Interoperability

> Why can't I simply replace `const getConfig = require("../../webpack.config.base");` with `import getConfig from "../../webpack.config.base"`?

```ts
const getConfig = require("../../webpack.config.base");
```

is a *CommonJS* import while

```ts
import getConfig from "../../webpack.config.base";
```

is an *ES6* import. They cannot be used interchangeable since they are inherently different. You should choose to work with one of them, but not both at the same time.